# Обновление БД через textbox

Tags: c#, база-данных, ado.net, обновления

Приветствую. Работаю в WForms. Есть база данных в которй находится таблица с ценами на материалы. Нужно написать код, что бы редактировать цену указанного материала. материалы и цены визуально представлены как динамически созданные GroupBox с картинкой, именем и ценой а не просто таблицей вроде DataGgidView. поэтому при редактировании новая цена пишется в текстбокс и передается вместе с именем материала в этот метод :

```
    public void saveNewMaterialNamePrise(int newPrise, string name)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                SqlCommand update = new SqlCommand(@"update Materials SET Prise=@priseNew where (Name =@selectedName)", conn);
                update.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"priseNew", newPrise);
                update.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"selectedName", name);
                SqlParameter parametrRow = update.Parameters.Add(@"selectedName", SqlDbType.Real, 10, "Name");
                parametrRow.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;
                conn.Open();
                adapter.UpdateCommand = update;
                DataSet _DDet = new DataSet(name);
                adapter.Update(_DDet );
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.Source);
        }
    }
```

Компилируется нормально но при выполнении выдает : Операции Update не удалось найти TableMaping или DataTable. Как я понимаю проблема с DataSet но решить не могу. Подскажите что неправильно. Спасибо!

Comment: Параметр `selectedName` задаётся в коде два раза, что явно ошибка. Датасет `_DDet` создаётся новый вызовом `new` - при этом он пустой. Естественно, обновлять нечего, данных-то в нём нет.

Comment: Вот в том и вопрос как заполнить DataSet данными.

Comment: Он уже должен быть заполнен. Не создавайте новый, берите тот, что использовался при получении данных из БД (методом `Fill`).

Comment: Я не использовал DataSet.

Comment: Метод `Fill` загружает данные из БД в датасет. Метод `Update` записывает данные из датасета обратно в БД. Переформулируйте вопрос, что именно хотите сделать.

Comment: Если `DataSet` не используется, то не нужно использовать `SqlDataAdapter`.

Comment: используется DataTable. но данные выводятся не в виде таблицы, а заполняют 
 List<int>. вопрос как обновить DataTable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось гораздо проще. Никаких Адаптеров и Датасетов вообще небыло нужно. А проблема решалась простым ExecuteNonQuery.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
  {
   SqlCommand update = new SqlCommand(@"update Materials SET Prise=@priseNew 
where (Name=@selectedName)", conn);
update.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"priseNew", newPrise);
update.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"selectedName", name);
conn.Open();
update.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
}
```